# Why does a large border-radius value cause chrome to hide the image?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, bulma

I have a 128px image with a border-radius to make it appear rounded (I'm actually using the `.is-rounded` class from Bulma to do this). This is the resulting CSS on the image:

```
.image img.is-rounded {
    border-radius: 9999px;
}
```

This works in Firefox but in Chrome, the image is hidden.

If I change it to the following, it works:

```
.image img.is-rounded {
    border-radius: 63px;
}
```

But anything beyond 63px, the image is hidden again:

```
.image img.is-rounded {
    border-radius: 64px;
}
```

You can see this on my personal website here: https://dominick.cc/

Chrome 110.0:

[image: What it looks like in Chrome 110.0]

Firefox:

[image: What it looks like in Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

I updated Chrome to 110.0.5481.100 and it seemed to resolve it. Weird!

Comment: i would delete the question because now it's useless since there is no more issue